# Callback interfaces provided by Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

I would like to know the list of all lambda interfaces provided by Codename One for callbacks. I remember: `Runnable`, `SuccessCallback<T>`, `FailureCallback<T>`, `OnComplete<T>`. Are there any others?

Are there interfaces that accept multiple parameters, like `SuccessCallback<T, K>`? Sometimes callbacks with two or three parameters might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's `LazyValue`. This is the list of callbacks built into Codename One. I'm excluding here dedicated callbacks like `ActionListener` etc.:

- `SuccessCallback`
- `FailureCallback`
- `OnComplete`
- `AsyncResult`
- `Callback` which implements both `SuccessCallback` and `FailureCallback`
- `LazyValue<T>` which accepts multiple Object arguments and returns `T`
- `RunnableWithResult`
- `RunnableWithResultSync`